# Use a class method without instantiating

Tags: c++, class, instance, point

I have a problem with a exercise of POO. The problem say:

> Add to the Point class of the previous exercise two public inline
>   methods that indicate the number of instances of the object type that
>   have been created and how many are in memory. Note: Accountants must
>   be private members of the class. Justify invoking the getCantCreated
>   and getCantExisting methods before creating any object.

But I compile the code, an error appears. It's:

`error: cannot call member function 'int Punto::getCantCreada()' without object`

How can I resolve it?

I know the problem comes from not instantiating an object, but how do I use this statement `Punto::getCantCreada()` without creating an object?
I read that this would be solved with static variables but in this case: What would its implementation be like?

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Punto{
  private:
    double mx;
    double my;
    int contInst = 0;
    int contExist = 0;
    void verificador1000();

  public:
    Punto(double x=0,double y=0);
    Punto(const Punto& p);
    ~Punto();
    int getCantCreada();
    int getCantExistente();
};

Punto::Punto(double x,double y){
  mx = x;
  my = y;
  contInst++;
  contExist++;
  verificador1000();
}
Punto::Punto(const Punto& p){
  mx = p.mx;
  my = p.my;
  contInst++;
  contExist++;
  verificador1000();
}

void Punto::verificador1000(){
  if(mx>1000) mx = 1000;
  if(mx<-1000) mx = -1000;
  if(my>1000) my = 1000;
  if(my<-1000) my = -1000;
}

int Punto::getCantCreada(){
  return contInst;
}
int Punto::getCantExistente(){
  return contExist;
}

void ff (void){
  Punto p,q,w;
  Punto h(34);
  Punto r=h;
  cout <<"a. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< r.getCantExistente()<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  cout <<"1. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;
  Punto p(12.34,-56.78);
  cout <<"2. Puntos Creados:"<<p.getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< p.getCantExistente()<<endl;
  Punto h(p);
  cout <<"3. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;
  ff();
  cout <<"4. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;

  std::cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Punto
{
private:
    double mx;
    double my;
    int contInst = 0;
    int contExist = 0;
    void verificador1000();

public:
    Punto(double x=0,double y=0);
    Punto(const Punto& p);
    ~Punto();
    int getCantCreada();
    int getCantExistente();
};

Punto::Punto(double x,double y)
{
    mx = x;
    my = y;
    contInst++;
    contExist++;
    verificador1000();
}
Punto::Punto(const Punto& p)
{
    mx = p.mx;
    my = p.my;
    contInst++;
    contExist++;
    verificador1000();
}

void Punto::verificador1000()
{
    if(mx>1000)
        mx = 1000;
    if(mx<-1000)
        mx = -1000;
    if(my>1000)
        my = 1000;
    if(my<-1000)
        my = -1000;
}

int Punto::getCantCreada()
{
    return contInst;
}
int Punto::getCantExistente()
{
    return contExist;
}

void ff (void)
{
    Punto p,q,w;
    Punto h(34);
    Punto r=h;
    cout <<"a. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< r.getCantExistente()<<endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout <<"1. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;
    Punto p(12.34,-56.78);
    cout <<"2. Puntos Creados:"<<p.getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< p.getCantExistente()<<endl;
    Punto h(p);
    cout <<"3. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;
    ff();
    cout <<"4. Puntos Creados:"<<Punto::getCantCreada()<< " - Existentes:"<< Punto::getCantExistente()<<endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Take out a piece of paper and write down, line by line, what your code is doing. You should end up with the following: each time an object of your class gets constructed, its `contInst` and `constExist` class members first get initialized to 0, then the class's constructor increments them to 1. The End. Now, after you wrote all of that down, ask yourself the following question: is this what you intend to happen, and, if so, how does that accomplish the original goals you intended to accomplish?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm sorry I don't understand your answer, if your answer is not to help with my problem please don't answer because it confuses you more. Thank you very much

Comment: I can confidently state that I'm not confused about anything. The bugs in the shown code are quite obvious.

Comment: That's why I'm here to ask what the mistake is and how to fix it. I'm not here to make riddles. Besides, one of my questions was clear, if you could do this: Punto::getCantCreada()

Comment: I think you still have to carefully consider _Sam's_ comment .. because you stated the purpose of your code .. and he mentioned that this code does not help with that requirement ... should you be not concerned with that then no need to _waste time_ stating what your code should achieve ... and just remove them from the question .. your question then should only be how to make the method _static_ ..

Comment: Y no era más fácil hacer lo que hizo Sid S, en vez de andar dando vueltas con la respuesta. Si yo utilizo el foro para preguntar acerca de una posible solución y que puedo corregir de mi codigo o en qué le erré concretamente. No para que me vengan a decir que lo revise de nuevo, se supone que si vine acá es porque no encontré el error o no sé a qué se debe. Saludos y que tengan buen dia.

Comment: Usually when one have an exercise to do, **the required concepts were given before**. So next time, better to listen more carefully your teacher. Go back to your course notes and read about **static** keywords. It should help.

Comment: Disculpa Phil1970 pero deberías entender que no todos los profesores explican bien y muchas veces uno no encuentra respuestas en ese profesor para entender bien sobre un tema concreto, por más que se lo preguntes 1500 veces. Por eso estoy acá y escribí esta pregunta. Que quede claro que yo no vengo a hacer que el trabajo o la tarea me la hagan los demás sino que vengo a evacuar dudas con personas que sé que tienen más experiencia que yo. Y con respecto al tema de static, busque en varios lados pero no encontré una explicación clara. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `error: cannot call member function 'int Punto::getCantCreada()' without object`
>
> How can I resolve it? I know the problem comes from not instantiating an object, but how do I use this statement `Punto::getCantCreada()`

If you make `contInst` static you can make `getCantCreada()` static, and then you can call `Punto::getCantCreada()` :

```
class Punto
{
  private:
    ...
    static int contInst;
    ...
  public:
    ...
    static int getCantCreada();
    ...
};

int Punto::contInst = 0;
```

Comment: Ah well, thank you. And what I read about the static variables for this case doesn't work either?